# Odoo workers give error for global variables

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, gunicorn, worker

I have developed some module that have some global variables.
the module is working good with the normal execution of the odoo.
But in one of the server if we change the odoo workers  by

> --workers=5

then in the fields_view_get method while I am trying to access that value i am not getting the value and it generates the error that variable is not defines or sometimes none type have no attribute.

The same problem were also occurs with the Gunicorn + Odoo.

Please provide the suggestions or reference if any.
All suggestions are appreciated.

code:

> ```
> @api.model
> def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
>     global lims_config
>     res = super(lims_dashboard_graph, self).fields_view_get(
>         view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
>     self = self.with_context(self._context)
>     if view_type == 'graph' and lims_config.get('graph_view') == 'bar':
>         print "\n BAR---Context--", self._context
>         doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
>         node = doc.xpath("//field[@name='date']")[0]
>         if lims_config.get('interval'):
>             node.set('interval', lims_config.get('interval'))
>         res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
>     return res
> ```

Comment: can you show us the `fields_view_get` method so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: @danidee,Thanks for the quick prompt, here in the question you can see the method

Answer (score 1):

Your python class is instantiated by the framework only once and the same instance is used for all database access. Keep that in mind when you work with class variables in Odoo, especially when you assign values to them.

Also, keep in mind that your class instance might be garbage cleaned and re-initialized.

When you use workers, more python processes are spawned and therefore more instances of your class are created without you knowing if proper initialization has taken place.

Bottom line: Do **not** use global variables in Odoo, there is always a better way. For example you can use one of the fields odoo provides to save some data that you want to use. Possibly char or text field that will only be stored in the database for you to use.